# Qt5 newline characters in translation text?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm working on correcting some missing translations from an application, and one particular translation isn't pulling the translated text from my TS file, and the culprit seems to be the newline character ("\n") in the source text, because when I remove that character from the source text and test the translation without the newline character in the string, it works.

So assuming I have a string like this in my TS file:

```
<context>
    <name>MyContext</name>
    <message>
        <source>The text that I'm trying to match.\nIt has a newline character.</source>
        <translation>The translated text.\nIt also has a newline character.</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

The char* string I'm translating also, obviously, has this newline character.

So how do I handle translation source strings with newline characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to write a helper method to split strings that have newlines into separated strings and also separate it into several entries in the TS file. Then it translated each line individually and stitches them back together with newlines.

I mean, it would be nice if the translation file supported newlines, but unless there's some other way of doing this, it'll have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Replace \n in between translation tags with an actual newline. This will update the translated GUI to have the newline.